# exclusions in sonar-project.properties being ignored

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-project.properties

I'm trying to exclude some c# files from duplicate code in Sonarqube by adding a new sonar-project.properties file to the root of my repository. I'm trying a "POC" where i've coped some C# files which are causing a high percentage of code duplication.

The sonar scanner runs as part of an azure pipeline

I've created the file, which looks like below:

```
sonar.projectKey=MyProjectName
sonar.projectName=MyProjectName //tried with and without 
sonar.projectVersion=1.0 //tried with and without 

sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8 //tried with and without 

# Enable the Visual Studio bootstrapper
sonar.visualstudio.enable=true //tried with and without 

sonar.sources=. //tried with and without 

# Duplication exclusions
sonar.cpd.exclusions=**/*Copy.cs

sonar.host.url=https://sonarqube.mydomain.com/ //tried with and without
```

My azure devops logs do seem to find the sonar-project.properties file:

```
2023-06-08T15:18:32.8604426Z INFO: Project root configuration file: D:\a\1\.sonarqube\out\sonar-project.properties
2023-06-08T15:18:33.1611676Z INFO: SonarScanner 4.8.0.2856
2023-06-08T15:18:33.1612569Z INFO: Java 11.0.19 Eclipse Adoptium (64-bit)
2023-06-08T15:18:33.1613584Z INFO: Windows Server 2022 10.0 amd64
2023-06-08T15:18:34.8396456Z INFO: User cache: C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.sonar\cache
2023-06-08T15:18:37.4347098Z INFO: Analyzing on SonarQube server 9.9.0.65466
2023-06-08T15:18:37.4359312Z INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "windows-1252" (analysis is platform dependent)
2023-06-08T15:18:38.9068139Z INFO: Load global settings
2023-06-08T15:18:39.1730647Z INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=281ms
2023-06-08T15:18:39.1815074Z INFO: Server id: B92B4E6C-AWu8amGVF99rjp3boDwD
2023-06-08T15:18:39.1972238Z INFO: User cache: C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.sonar\cache
2023-06-08T15:18:39.2010963Z INFO: Load/download plugins
2023-06-08T15:18:39.2011725Z INFO: Load plugins index
2023-06-08T15:18:39.3360359Z INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=125ms
2023-06-08T15:18:45.6208126Z INFO: Load/download plugins (done) | time=6409ms
2023-06-08T15:18:46.7428102Z INFO: Loaded core extensions: developer-scanner
2023-06-08T15:18:48.0460701Z INFO: Process project properties
2023-06-08T15:18:48.1062471Z INFO: Process project properties (done) | time=63ms
2023-06-08T15:18:48.1084980Z INFO: Execute project builders
2023-06-08T15:18:48.2251995Z INFO: Execute project builders (done) | time=125ms
2023-06-08T15:18:48.2401855Z INFO: Project key: MyProjectName
2023-06-08T15:18:48.2402677Z INFO: Base dir: D:\a\1\s
2023-06-08T15:18:48.2403366Z INFO: Working dir: D:\a\1\.sonarqube\out\.sonar
2023-06-08T15:18:48.2554167Z INFO: Load project settings for component key: 'MyProjectName'
2023-06-08T15:18:48.3804222Z INFO: Load project settings for component key: 'MyProjectName' (done) | time=125ms
```

The exclusions are ignored, it's as if the exclusions are overriden? Do i need to enable reading from the `sonar-project.properties` file or should it happen automatically when added?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The correct parameter to apply exclusions is **sonar.exclusions**. In essence, this parameter will ignore any file (or pattern of files) from being scanned.

You can put it on the config file like this:

```
sonar.exclusions=test**,top/test**,**Copy.cs
```

Or call it from the cmd line as this:

```
-Dsonar.exclusions=globalconfig.inc,test**,top/test**,**Copy.cs
```

Note that in order for exclusions to work correctly, you must:

- Change directories to forward slashes. i.e: top\test must be renamed top/test
- Use double asterisk characters. i.e: **Copy.cs
- Be aware that names are Case Sensitive